# Replace <div> tag with <p> tag using php

Tags: php, html, css

```
<div style = "text-align:left;" class="ref"> Text </div>
```

I want to replace `<div>` with `<p>` without losing attributes.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Strange requirements

Comment: Try DomDocument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
$str = '<div style = "text-align:left;" class="ref"> Text </div>';

$newstr = preg_replace('/<div [^<]*?class="([^<]*?ref.*?)">(.*?)<\/div>/','<p class="$1">$2</p>',$str);

echo $newstr;
```

Output : `<p class="ref"> Text </p>`